# Trying to use JavaScript client-side to get main image from a specific webpage using URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a solution to getting these images. Basically when the page is loaded it has an array of links to other pages on the same site. I am after an idea of how to use javascript to get an image each url in the array to display on the page. Unfortunately it would be a lot trickier to do this on the server as this code is loaded on many different sites which is why I'm looking for a client-side solution.

Thanks =]

Comment: You can use JS to create `<img>` tags dynamically on your page and give each one a `href` attribute with the links you have, the images will then be loaded and displayed

Comment: @LcLk Unfortunately I don't have links to the images, I only have links to the webpages. Getting the links to the images from those webpages is the barrier I'm trying to overcome at the minute. I'm currently investigating using RegEx to find img tags in each page and find the image src's from that, but would love any other advice.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your problem. Thanks for clarifying. That plan would work but involves loading every page you want to show images for but that sounds like the only client side solution to me. But I'll let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: You can not do that using client-side JavaScript – the Same Origin Policy will prevent you from accessing the content of the other URLs (unless they would be specifically allowing you to do so, keyword CORS.)